# Animations with extra objects

Tags: animation

I'd like to make multiple animations for a game character, but some of the animations should use extra objects like weapons that the other animations and the base character doesn't have by default.

---

*Things I thought of as solutions:*

**1,**
Merging the object with the character and making it hidden in the animations where it's not in use. - but I fear it'd be affected for the performance

**2,**
Using a completely different object (hidden by default) with its own rig and snapping that object to the required character bone.

What would be the best solution? Do you have any other ideas?
Is there any standard method that is used in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 is quite the standard method. Except you don't really "hide" the object, you invoke it when needed and delete it when no more useful (ie, when you change weapon or throw it). Of course, it depends of the game engine, but that's more or less always how you do it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!


How should the animation process look like in Blender?


Should I just select the two armatures of the character and the extra object and just like in any other animation process inserting keyframes? So the only difference here is there are two armatures instead of one?


How is the invoke part looks like in Blender? Does it even a thing in Blender or is this only exists in the game engines?

Comment: You don't need two armature ! A single armature can have many Childs objects.Let say you have an armature already deforming the character. Select the weapon, then select the hand bone (in pose mode), press ctrl+p and choose "Bone"

Comment: The "invoke" (also called "instantiate") part isn't a thing in Blender, you should hide/unhide instead. Or better (for performances), disable it (in the outliner, the "screen" icon which is hidden by default).